# Customizing a TListBox to resemble an Outlook list

Tags: delphi, article, tlistview

Please down vote me if this is not appropriate, but I'm desperate to the point of pulling my hair out looking for this link. This is really a last resort.

Recently I browsed to a blog (at least I think it was) that had a very detailed description on how to modify a TListBox to have a multi-line look resembling some of the entries on an outlook list of emails, with a Title and the initial content. It was a particular good example because it had all the code for the modified TItem and TItemList objects and loads of images with that look

I've scoured my Firefox History, my Chrome history, my FeedDemon Feeds and my Google Bookmarks to no avail. I've done Google searches with TListBox, TListView, TItems, TItemList, Custom, Extending and some other variations and even looked 3 page results down to no avail...

Has anyone stumbled upon this article?
Please let an "old" man recover his memory, and his sanity :)

Cheers,
Gus

Answer (score 2):

[How to use](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16) is the one that "TListbox Ownerdraw Delphi" finds for me. Certainly Ownerdraw is what you are looking at to do this sort of thing. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this article is for TListView and I'm now certain that it was a TListBox.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question with a proper answer:

[Blaise Pascal Magazine](http://www.blaisepascal.eu/) [Issue 4 November 2008](http://blaise-pascal.eu/index.php?actie=./blaisepascal_4/issue4) [page 27](http://blaise-pascal.eu/paydownloads/Nr4/BlaiseUK4Downloadable.pdf).

Comment: That is issue 4 (http://blaise-pascal.eu/index.php?actie=./blaisepascal_4/issue4) which can also be downloaded: http://blaise-pascal.eu/paydownloads/Nr4/BlaiseUK4Downloadable.pdf the link name suggests this was unintended btw

Comment: Thanks, added links to the appropriate locations.